# UIActivityIndicatorView not working when added to UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm trying to add a UIActivityIndicatorView to the center of my UITableView while it waits for the UITableViews data to load. I am doing this as follows:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorTemp = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
[activityIndicatorTemp setCenter:[[self tableView] center]];
[self setActivityIndicator: activityIndicatorTemp]; 
[activityIndicatorTemp release];
[[self tableView] addSubview:activityIndicator];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

However the activity indicator is not showing up at all when I launch the code. I'd like to do it programmatically, any suggestions on how to fix this or why it isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is when I was setting the location of the activityindicator. I did this before the tableview had been initialized.

```
[activityIndicatorTemp setCenter:[[self tableView] center]];
```

I removed the above and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

please move

```
[activityIndicatorTemp release];
```

after addSubview:

```
[[self tableView] addSubview:activityIndicator];
```

Comment: or at the very end. doesn't matter when its after addSubview.

Comment: Appreciate the response. Still couldn't get it to work. Don't understand why this would matter since I already retained the temp variable when I set it to activity Indicator.